# Building $A_k$ such that $\displaystyle\bigcup_{k\in \mathbb{N}}A_{k} = \mathbb{R}$ and $\displaystyle\bigcap_{k\in \mathbb{N}}A_{k} = \mathbb{N}$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, real-numbers

I wanted to know how I can find a sequence of sets according to a particular union and intersection of these sets? For example:

> Build a sequence of sets such that
>
> $$\bigcup_{k\in \mathbb{N}}A_{k} = \mathbb{R}$$
>
> and
>
> $$\bigcap_{k\in \mathbb{N}}A_{k} = \mathbb{N}$$

Is there a special method or just guess and try?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Every $A_k$ obviously has to contain ${\Bbb N}$. But without further conditions on the sets there are simply too many ways to obtain ${\Bbb R}$ as a union.

Answer (score 2):

**Example 1**

Take $A_1=\mathbb R$, $A_2=A_3=...=\mathbb N$, and we are done !

**Example 2**

A probably more interesting example, take for all $k$, $$A_k=\bigcup_{i=-\infty }^\infty \left[i-\frac{1}{k},i+\frac{1}{k}\right].$$

Comment: In the 2nd case $$\bigcap_{k\in \mathbb{N}}A_{k} = \mathbb{Z}$$ not $$\bigcap_{k\in \mathbb{N}}A_{k} = \mathbb{N}$$

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo: It's true, but it's very easy to adapte it to get $\mathbb N$. Thank you anyway for your comment. I will nevertheless let it like this and let the OP adapt the proof as an exercise.

Comment: Thank you for your answer ! What if the sets have to be distinctive ? so there is no possibility to set A2=A3=...=N.

Comment: @J.Doe: My second example is a good one :-) Just adapt the proof to not have $\mathbb Z$ but $\mathbb N$.

Comment: Yes thank you ! I just read your comment now.

Comment: @Surb: is it sufficient to write i, i +1/k ? Thanks.

Comment: @J.Doe: It will also give $\mathbb Z$. Remark that $A_1=A_2=\mathbb R$. Then, It sufficient to take $A_1=\mathbb R$ and $A_k=\bigcup_{i=0}^\infty \left[i-\frac{1}{k},i+\frac{1}{k}\right]$.

Comment: @Surb Yes, I was thinking about taking i from 0 to infinity but doesn't that give you R+ for every Ak ? because you take all the numbers from 0 to infinity so adding or subtracting by a constant each time does not change anything: I'll still have all the numbers from 0 to infinity so that at the end the intersection between all the Ak will be R+. I'm a bit confused. Thks !

Comment: If $A_1=\mathbb R$, the union will automatically make $\mathbb R$ since $A_k\subset \mathbb R$ for all $k\geq 2$. The intersection will make $\mathbb N$. For the intersection it will be $n$ (notice that the $A_k$ are decreasing, and $diam(A_k)\underset{k\to \infty }{\longrightarrow }0$, then it can't be $\mathbb R^+$.)

Comment: oh okk, I got it ! Thanks a lot for your time and your answers !

Answer (score -1):

The case with $\mathbb R$/$\mathbb N$ is just an example, but the general case is just as easy.

The union consists of any element that is in just one of the $A_k$'s, so set $A_1$ to be that union.

All your $A_k$'s have to contain the intersection, so set the rest of the $A_k$'s to be the intersection. - And you're done.